# How to remove text from a string with javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a url likes this:

> http://abc-efff7b80a1e5b2.xyz.com

I would like to remove some text like that:

> http://abc.xyz.com

Comment: Is this fixed or dynamic ?

Comment: Is this static text "-efff7b80a1e5b2"  or changed dynamically ?

Comment: @Husen It is dynamic.

Comment: Something should be fixed length or format. Please provide some information regarding this.

Comment: @Husen It isn't fix length or format.

Comment: @LazyCatIT if the text is between - and . just replace the text with nothing ("")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Regex` will be a fairly easy way to solve this.

`.replace(/\-.*?\./, '.')` this replaces all text between `-` and `.`

```js
var str = "http://abc-efff7b80a1e5b2.xyz.com";
str = str.replace(/\-.*?\./, '.');
console.log(str)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @RanaGhosh Cheers for the kind words

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it will work generally, but this might do trick.

```
>>a
"http://abc-efff7b80a1e5b2.xyz.com"
>>re
>>a.replace(a.match(re)[0], "")
"http://abc.xyz.com"
```

```js
  function sanitize(url, regx) {
    return url.replace(url.match(regx)[0], "");
  }
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('tr')).forEach(e=> e.children[1].innerHTML = sanitize(e.children[0].innerHTML, /(?:\-\w+)/));
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>http://abc-8n0qhnb9.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-q265r4by.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-xiwugpkf.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-wbojtv02.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-wf5aw904.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-vp37wiex.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-y04xag44.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-gw5nz2v0.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-0lu1r5bb.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-2r1o6r0l.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-bhs9gapw.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-j1b0ickq.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-8be4kis9.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-hcufvqot.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-eeeze0w9.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-0ya1j44x.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-jmquwmc2.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-6rjg674m.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-tajrtltl.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-y2k01kmn.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-rujlhgjf.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-r18o2cm9.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-23lemwng.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-bvsa71rj.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-ydxycm8w.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-79rwm0td.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-cpe62kkn.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-6u5uby9k.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-2a032pvi.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
<tr><td>http://abc-1c0poy7q.xyz.com</td><td></td>></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `spilt` for doing this. Please follow the below code::

```
var url = 'http://abc-efff7b80a1e5b2.xyz.com';
var split_url = url.split('.');
var start_url = split_url[0].split('-')[0];
var full_url = start_url + '.' + split_url[1] + '.' + split_url[2];
console.log(full_url);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be very easy. Get the value and the use the replace method.

```js
$('button').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var str = $('#txt').val();
  var regex = /(https?:\/\/abc)(\-.+)(.xyz.com)/ig
  str= str.replace(regex, "$1$3")
  $('#txt').val(str)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="http://abc-efff7b80a1e5b2.xyz.com" id="txt"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<button type="button">Change value</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ty this:

```js
var url = "http://abc-efff7b80a1e5b2.xyz.com";
url = url.replace(/-.*x/, '.x');
console.log(url);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```